# Using Laravel in Docker Using public under Resource Tips 403 Access denied

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I configured dnmp (PHP development environment) using docker compose in Docker, but I did not use the nginx here separately and opened another Nginx Proxy Manager service. The Laravel page can be displayed normally, but the resources I imported are giving a 403 error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PGPK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nV4C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83IlK.png)

I want to be able to access these resources normally

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It is a configuration issue with Nginx. Although Nginx knows that there is a file, it sends the request to PHP, and then PHP rejects this request, resulting in a 403 error.